# I can't seem to figure out how to pass a JSON object to a class residing in a different module

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Currently learning duck typing, but I can't seem to figure out how to use classes properly. I feel like an idiot.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my main file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = api.get_result(api.build_search_url(getLocations(getNumLocations())))
    getSteps(getNumSteps())
    api.GrabSteps.calculate(result)
```

And the class in api.py:

```
class GrabSteps:

    def __init__(self, json_result):
        self._json_result = json_result

    def calculate(self, json_result):
        print('DIRECTIONS')
        x = 0
        steps = len(json_result['route']['legs'])
        print(steps)
        while x < steps:
            for item in json_result['route']['legs'][x]['maneuvers']:
                print(item['narrative'])
            x += 1
```

I have made sure that the variable `result` is being stored properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one problem is this: `GrabSteps` is a class, so you need to instantiate it before calling `calculate`:

```
gs = api.GrabSteps(result)
gs.calculate(result)
```

I'm not entirely sure what arguments you're supposed to pass in. Both the `__init__` and `calculate` take a json result, but I don't know if you should be passing in the same result or not. The core of the problem is, you need to instantiate the class before using it to calculate something.